# How to build and deploy Spring Boot no-web app to TomEE?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have a simple Spring Boot JMS app like [this](https://gist.github.com/IvanZelenskyy/96545f39ef51727ed92d67f8b7b5cd11). It have no web-layer and I don't want to add web layer to that app. It should be just one JMS microservice, hidden from web.
But I want to run it inside TomEE (as EJB or something). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy your app as an ear without any webmodule. Alternatively you can deploy it to openejb-standalone instead of tomee.